# How to Download Youtube video in Django App to my Local direct from Browser Using PyTube Library?

Tags: django, pytube

```
def download(request):
  obj = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Sj-UdjqlFw')
  obj.streams.first().download()  #what path sould i give into download() as param
  return render(request, 'downloader/home.html',context={})
```

The video is download into my Django Root Directory. But I want to download it into my Local Directory like Desktop or Download folder.

Answer (score 0):

change `obj.streams.first().download()` to `obj.streams.first().download('your/path/')`

Comment: I tried. But my problem is, I want to download it from browser to direct my download folder. What path should I give in download() method?

Comment: you can use ' ../ ' to go back a folder. for example: stream.download('../../../baback/Downloads')

Comment: Still download in my server directory.